# Fast data extraction algorithm

Tags: algorithm, information-extraction

I have to 2 utf-8 text files. In each row of the file there is string, that can contain language specific characters like Ü, Ö, ą, ę. Strings are random order and length and can repeat. In the first file there is at least 3 mln of rows (it can easy exceed 1 mld of rows). The second file is smaller it usually get about 400 thousands of rows (but can be much bigger).

I need to create new file that contains entries from file one with removed entries that appear in file two and all repeatings entries.

Currently I'm sorting both files and remove repeating entries. Next I'm writing them to new file while checking if they appear in the second file.

Is there any faster way to do this?

Edit

Memory is a problem. I don't copy this strings to memory, buy operate on files.  My friend suggested not to copy to memory, but work on file streams. After this execution time drop significantly.

Administrator of computer don't want to install data-base on it.

After sort my code rune like this in loop:

```
if stringFromFile1 < stringFromFile2 then writeToFile3 and get next stringFromFile1
else if stringFromFile1 == stringFromFile2 then dropStringFromFile1 and get next stringFromFile1
else if stringFromFile1 > stringFromFile2 then get next stringFromFile2 and go to line 1
```

Comment: 1 billion? does the data fit into memory?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a data structure available such as a hash set you could *just* iterate over the files and add each line. Sets do not allow repetition and a hashset *should* provide you with a constant way of checking if an element already exists (in Java at least, the `add` method checks if an element exists, if it does not, it adds the item to the set in constant time).

Once you have gone through both files, you can then iterate over the hash set and store its content to the file. This should provide you with an algorithm that can in linear time.

Forgot to mention: I am assuming that you do not have restrictions on memory consumption. If you do, you might want to try saving each line to a database, using the hash of each line as a primary key. Inserting elements with two primary keys should fail, thus making sure that you have unique strings in the database. Once you will be done with the insertions, you can retrieve and store the values from the database to a file.

Answer (score 0):

My proposal is to preprocess file two and form tree structure from it. For example, say you have this kind of file two:

```
bad
bass
absent
```

then your tree structure would be like this:

```
BEGIN -> b -> a -> d -> END
|             |
|             + -> s -> s -> END
|
+-> a -> b -> s -> e -> n -> t -> END
```

`END` designates word delimiter (be it space or new line or something else)

Then you open file one into file stream and read it out byte after byte. Once you encounter beginning of the file or pick next character after delimiter you start walking your tree. If with streamed bytes you can walk it to the `END`, it means you found matching word and you should discard it. If not, the word is unique and need not be dropped. If found unique, the word must be added into tree structure to discard its further repetitions.

Tree structure will take substantial amount memory, but it is anyway less than holding unique words in some sort of array

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possible optimizations.

As Roman Saveljev suggested, you can keep a trie structure in memory. Depending on the entropy of the data, it can easily fit in memory.

As the 2nd file is sorted, you can run a binary search to check if the record is there (if you aren't doing this yet).

You can also keep a Bloom Filter in memory to easily check those records that aren't duplicated to avoid going to disk everytime.